# Unity 3.5.6 compile error on mac mini for iOS

Tags: ios, macos, compiler-errors, unity-game-engine

I got compile error and do not know how to fix it:

**Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:**

```
"_mono_aot_module_Assembly_UnityScript_firstpass_info", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

In build settings for valid architectures only **armv7** choosen.

Comment: What Platform are you building? iOS, mac desktop? If iOS, have you tried deleting whole XCode project and building it once again?

Comment: Platform is iOS (iPhone) and yes I deleted project and generated it again, but it is not helped

Comment: I suspect to ProjectSettings.asset and svn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll.s and Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll.s to xcode project